# assign variable value thought GET method in Python

Tags: python, rest, flask, get

I have the below `python` code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

import requests

    @app.route("/get_city")
    get_city():
        to_echo = request.args.get("city", "")
        response = "{}".format(to_echo)
    
        return response
    
    
    @app.route('/v1/api/check_current_weather_by_city')
    def check_current_weather_by_city():
        city = get_city()
```

What is the correct way for getting the value "Tel+aviv" into the variable `city`? the current implementation is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly, `requests.get()` is *not* part of Flask (which has a subtly-different `request` value in a request) and is another 3rd party library which will return some [Request object](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content), which you probably want the `.text` property of

This could be

```py
r = requests.get(url)
r.raise_for_status()  # make sure the request succeeded!
city = r.text
```

However, you are probably better off describing your logic such that the minimum amount is in the flask app and the majority is in a library you import!

Then you can directly call functions in that library if you want their logic in multiple routes without making a web request.

```py
from mylibrary import myfunction

@route("/foo")
def foo():
    myfunction(arg1)

@route("/bar")
def bar():
    myfunction(arg2)
```

Anecdotally, this style will also make your project much easier to unit test (I have worked with several Flask projects).

Comment: So my call should be `city = echo("Tel-aviv")`? I tried but it still throw exception

Comment: You cannot directly call the route like that, you should make another function and have _both_ call it

Comment: can you share an example based on my code?

Comment: just declare a function that's outside of both routes and call it

Comment: I didn't understand. what `myfunction` does? Why I can't call `get_city()` with param like that: `@app.route("/get_city/<city>")`   `city = get_city("Tel-aviv")`?

Comment: just create a new file with your common logic in a function! but you can first try it out by having the common logic in a function somewhere in the same file as your flask app routes (just don't decorate it with a route). I recall the [route decorator](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.route) interferes with calling it directly